# How to perfom an action when Tab in a CustomTabBar is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls

I have a CustomTabBar created working as expected. Apart from selecting tabs, I want to perform an action (refresh some info) on one of my viewcontrollers when this tab is already selected. I mean, I have a tab selected and I press that tab again and fire an action of the ViewController.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If your custom tab bar controller is a subclass of UITabBarController then you can provide a delegate that responds to `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`. In iOS 3.0 or later this will still fire if the view controller is the same as the one already selected, so you can track this and send your update messages to the correct view controller in this case.

If you don't subclass UITabBarController and have written the tab bar changing code yourself, then implementing a delegate protocol and sending notifications of tab changes and other events is probably a good idea.